Talend how to handle multiple row headers?
I am building a pipeline using Talend to ingest data from Share point and output to Snowflake. Currently using dynamic schema as there will be many other files with different structure.
current problem is that I have a multi-row headers file as below:
current headers
the top row are merged cell where when I tried to output to a Snowflake  table, it will count the second cell as null, empty. I want to transform the header before output it to Snowflake into below:
final headers basically a 1 row header
is there any way to solve this? idk if I explain this correctly
I have tried to only take the headers as rows and merge the 2 rows together but idk how to do it when using dynamic schema since I cannot see the column name's.
the current test pipeline are input the pipeline using tFileInputExcel and tried to merge the rows using tJavaRow and then just tLogRow to display
